# How to add drawablePadding only for one side

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

Is there any way to add drawablePadding only right not for all

```
 <EditText
       android:hint="Contact number"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:drawablePadding="2dp"
       android:id="@+id/et_mobile_number"
       android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mobile"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </EditText>
```

Like this    `android:paddingRight=""` for drawable image

Comment: android:drawablePadding  will only create padding between the drawable and the Text if you want to set drawble padding set a padding to the editText itself

Comment: No.you should set custom views instead.

Answer (score 2):

can you please try to add this line to your edittext and check whether it solve your issue.

```
 android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mobile"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_mobile"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```